# Google Sheets - Find most recent Sunday in group list of dates

Tags: date, google-sheets, max

First of all, I will preemptively say thank you for any help provided even if the solution doesn't work. I'm learning a lot about Google Sheets these days mostly from this community and various threads.

I am trying to track the most recent individual day that something has been used. The item is used on various days of the week, but I need the most recent time it was used on a Sunday (for example). I know =MAX returns most recent, but how do I filter that down to just the most recent of a single day? I've tried some variations of IF statements and WEEKDAY and such. But, I'm clearly missing something.

=IF(G2:P2(WEEKDAY(1)),MAX)

Answer (score 1):

You could try with MAX and FILTER. Let me know if it's useful!

```
=MAX(FILTER(G2:P2,WEEKDAY(G2:P2)=1))
```